# nvidia-settings crash while on Intel graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I've added the `xorg-edgers` PPA using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`. Then I've tried different packages, all with the same problem. I'm currently using `nvidia-331` as it's working almost perfectly.

The only problem that's left is that `nvidia-settings` is working perfectly when I'm using nVidia graphics, but as soon as I switch to Intel graphics (I'm on a notebook with nVidia Optimus) `nvidia-settings` won't open (it crashes instantly). Executing `nvidia-settings` in the terminal only gives me:

```
** Message: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? yes
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I used the following commands to install `nvidia-331`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia*
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I can't use the nVidia drivers in Ubuntu's repository as the performance is horrible on my Notebook. However, `nvidia-settings` never had those problems using Ubuntu's repository.

**Update:** seems to be a bug (LP [#1214508](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/1214508)). However, they claim all packages >= 319 are affected, but it was working just fine using `nvidia-331` from Ubuntu's repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that anything from xorg-edgers PPA is just for those who really knows to fix their system. I spent a lot of time doing so (reverting packages).
Therefore I really recommended removing this PPA after you install the latest NVIDIA driver.
By the way: I'm reverted back from 337/334 to 331.38 nvidia version (from standard 14.04 repository) since I need CUDA and OpenCL support.

Now back to the topic:
- I don't think that we, as a NVIDIA proprietary driver users, can do anything about the buggy NVIDIA PRIME tools.

How to revert back to your discrete NVIDIA card:

1.) "sudo prime-select nvidia" proposed by Louis Matthijssen worked in my case.
Of course I logged out and in afterwards.

2.) Another "solution" would be switching from NVIDIA Optimus to "Discrete card" in your BIOS (if you have there such an option).
    (not tested)

Comment: Yes, I'm using `nvidia-current` from Ubuntu's repository now and everything is working as it should now (so far). I didn't want to use this one as I'm experiencing lag spikes in games when I'm using it, but this seems to solve itself after a few minutes gaming.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue. If I remove all the Nvidia packages and Prime and re-install and then reboot without changing anything I get access to the Nvidia settings. As soon as I swap to the IGP I can no longer swap back to the discrete GPU.

I have tried with different nvidia drivers and it is exactly the same result. Initially I was getting ACPI errors in the logs but now it just logs the Segment Faults (error 4 in libc-2.19.so).

Any ideas?

Comment: You can still switch using `sudo prime-select nvidia` or `sudo prime-select intel`, but it's just annoying that it doesn't work. Also, this is not really an answer.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please take a few minutes to go through the [site tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to get a general idea of how this site works and how to make the most of it.